# Use the shell method to set up and evaluate the integral that gives the volume of the solid generated by revolving the plane region about x = 6.

Tags: calculus

y = x, y = 0, x = 3. 
Revolving around x = 6, what is the volume of the shape formed using shell method?

I've tried this:

http://www3.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP447521i89ce0d69c7cb5000040fc75g3e5g51hca?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=44

From what I've researched online and from my notes in class, this should be working but I can't find what I'm doing wrong. 
I've also tried integrating from 3 to 6. Not sure what else I could be doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: please include your thoughts about questions or what You have treid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At any $x$, you have a shell whose radius is $6-x$ and whose height is $x$, so its volume is $2\pi x(6-x)\Delta x$.

Answer (score 4):

$2\pi\int_0^3(6-x)(x-0)\mathbb dx=2\pi\int_0^3(6x-x^2)\mathbb dx=2\pi [3x^2-\frac{x^3}3]_0^3=2\pi[18-0]=36\pi$

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't thinking about it in the sense of subtracting but rather adding the extra length so I was stuck with adding 3.

Comment: Sure.  The radius is $(6-x)$, when rotating about $x=6$...